# Translate SQL query to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, translate

**THIS USER HAS ALREADY ASKED THE EXACT DUPLICATE A FEW MINUTES AGO [sql and linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552190/sql-and-linq-query)**

`PhotoAlbums` table
AlbumID
Title
Date

`Photos` table:
PhotoID
Title
Date
AlbumID

```
SELECT     AlbumID, Title, Date,
                          (SELECT     TOP (1) PhotoID
                            FROM          Photos AS c
                            WHERE      (AlbumID = a.AlbumID)) AS PhotoID
FROM         PhotoAlbums AS a
```

I need this query written in LINQ-to-SQL. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552190/sql-and-linq-query

Comment: Are you aware that the result of TOP(1) is indeterminate when you supply no order by clause? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261625/sql-server-why-do-these-queries-return-different-result-sets

Comment: your query is inefficient, as it must run a different query to find the photo for each row returned from PhotoAlbums.  You would be much better off using a derived table and joining PhotoAlbums to that.

Comment: @jason: i stuck up at the start... first line of expression in brackets is problem. In LINQ there's no SELECT and TOP keyword.

Comment: @ile: There is a `select` in Linq, and instead of `TOP (n)` you can use `Take(n)`, although in this example since you only need `TOP(1)`, you can use `First`.

Comment: @Fredou: yes, but at the end I decided to separate building SQL query from translating it to LINQ.

Comment: @KM: I don't understand you exactly.. isn't your query also running a different query?

Comment: @ile, my query runs one derived table query to find 1 row for each album and it then joins back those all of those rows, this query runs a different individual query for each album row, a whole order of magnitude slower.  in sql, less actual code does not mean a better query, and subtle differences can make huge performance differences.

Comment: I see... I'm not that good in SQL so I don't know how much does it actually reflects on performance

Comment: @ile, the more rows to add to PhotoAlbums, the slower your query will run.  my version should stay fast.  if you don't expect to have many rows, don't worry, but you should try and learn the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have defined a relationship between `PhotoAlbums` and `Photos` in your DBML file, you can do this:

```
var albums = dataContext.PhotoAlbums.Select(album => new {
    AlbumId = album.AlbumId,
    Title = album.Title
    Date = album.Date,
    PhotoId = album.Photos.Select(photo => photo.PhotoId).FirstOrDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
var result = 
   yourContext.PhotoAlbums.Select(a => 
      new {a.AlbumId, a.Title, a.Date, a.Photos.First().PhotoId }
   );
```

Also, [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a very nice tool, that can help you do this.